# My android application is not fetching the data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

hi there I am trying to fetch the data from Firebase but it is not fetching the data.
Below the java code I'm using:

```
package com.example.cashiya;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    dalyCheckCard = findViewById(R.id.dailycheckcard);
    luckyCard = findViewById(R.id.luckyspincard);
    taskCard = findViewById(R.id.taskcard);
    redeemCard = findViewById(R.id.redeemcard);
    watchCard = findViewById(R.id.watchcard);
    aboutCard = findViewById(R.id.aboutcard);
    referCard = findViewById(R.id.referalcard);
    profileImage = findViewById(R.id.profileImg);
    coinsTv = findViewById(R.id.coinTv);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    nameTv = findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
    emailTv = findViewById(R.id.emailTV);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
    getDataFromDatabase();


    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            DashboardActivity.this, drawerLayout, toolbar,
            R.string.opendrawer, R.string.closedrawer);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id==R.id.dailycheckcard){
                Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Yar sabar karo hale kam ho reya", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (id==R.id.luckyspincard){
                Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Yar sabar karo hale kam ho reya", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (id==R.id.taskcard){
                Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Yar sabar karo hale kam ho reya", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (id==R.id.referalcard){
                Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Yar sabar karo hale kam ho reya", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (id==R.id.aboutcard){
                Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Yar sabar karo hale kam ho reya", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (id==R.id.watchcard){
                Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Yar sabar karo hale kam ho reya", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Sabar te hai hi nai", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }




            return true;
        }
    });

}

private void getDataFromDatabase(){
    reference.child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            ProfileModel model = snapshot.getValue(ProfileModel.class);
            nameTv.setText(model.getName());
            emailTv.setText(model.getEmail());
            coinsTv.setText(String.valueOf(model.getCoins()));
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(model.getImage())
                    .timeout(6000)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profile)
                    .into(profileImage);




        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Error: " +
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();

        }
    });
}
```

}

It was working ok but when I add navigation bar then it stop fetching I am just trying to fetch user name and email from firebase. Application is not crashing its just not fetching the data from firebase.

bellow is the sign in activity

```
package com.example.cashiya;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    register = findViewById(R.id.registerTv);
    emailEdit = findViewById(R.id.emailEdit);
    passwordEdit = findViewById(R.id.passwordEdit);
    loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = emailEdit.getText().toString();
            String password = passwordEdit.getText().toString();

            if (email.isEmpty()){
                emailEdit.setError("Please enter valid E-Mail");
                return;
            }
            if (password.isEmpty()){
                passwordEdit.setError("Invalid Password");
                return;
            }
            signIn(email,password);
        }
    });
}
private void signIn(String email, String password){

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

   auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).
           addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {

           if (task.isSuccessful()){

               progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

               Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);

           }else {
               progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error: " +
                       task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }

       }
   });
}
```

}

Comment: if the app is crashing then please add the stacktrace. Thanks

Comment: no application is working ok its just not showing the data from firebase

Comment: Can you include the Firebase database structure since we don't have any idea if your code structure is correct or not.

Comment: i am allowing the users to sign in through email and password

Comment: i have added the the signin activity code

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?